# Fastest way to process php & mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, hosting

I am looking for any kind of way to process php & mysql faster than my MacBook Pro running XAMPP is able to do.

I have written an application, that has to process a lot of data for some simulations. On my MB, this takes about half an hour each time I want run a simulation. Not so very handy.

Is there a good (and cheap) way to process these simulations a bit faster? I already enabled MySQL-Caches and PHP eAccelerator - but it's just simply too slow. I'd love a service, where I could place some MySQL-DB, some PHP and gain a lot of processing-power.

Is there something faster than XAMPP to tun this?

Comment: HALF AN HOUR??? Holy sh**... What are you doing with it? Other languages like Java or even C++ might be better suited to do large simulations. Also, it's not XAMPP which is slow (it's just a collection of tools you need) but your machine is most likely not powerful enough.

Comment: or use an online host don't waste time using your own local server on a laptop

Comment: @LukasKnuth Yeah, sorry... half an hour is quite a bit... ;-) I don't know C++ or Java enough to do all those simulations.

Comment: @Qchmqs I thought about this - but most hosts are limiting php max_execution_time. Is there a good host just for some calculations? No webhosting needed, just php&mysql

Comment: try to compile your php code using hipHop or something

Comment: or better start thinking about rewriting in c++ or c 
i dont think php is the best solution for simulations

Comment: @user966812 You'll need to by or at least rent a server to change the `php.ini`-file, most free-hosters don't allow that. An other idea would be using [Googles APP-Engine](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/) (if you know Python) or [Amazons E2](http://aws.amazon.com/de/php/) (which works with PHP if I'm right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, performance is difficult to determine without going into details about your implementation so I can't really offer much advice beyond a few tips:

As the commenters mention, PHP isn't designed for number crunching; something like Python, Java, or C++ are far better suited to this kind of task.

Is 30 minutes a reasonable amount of time for the task to take? Assuming it takes 10 minutes less, will that actually be worth spending money on?  Better planning and running jobs overnight is far cheaper :)

As far as alternatives go you could try running your jobs on an Amazon EC2 instance, which may give you a bit of a speed boost but you'll still be running on one core; so your simulation will run roughly as quickly, ignoring input/output.

If you actually want to optimise it, profile your application. You need to know where the time's being spent so you can figure out which parts you should spend time optimising; once you know which part of the code takes so long you should be able to try different approaches to get it working faster. Make sure you know the [quirks](http://labs.phurix.net/posts/50-php-optimisation-tips-revisited) of PHP, there are some surprising performance differences you might not be aware of. Optimisation can help, but always make sure your time spent doing it is going to be worth the time it saves.

Comment: I actually laughed out loud when reading the [quirks](http://labs.phurix.net/posts/50-php-optimisation-tips-revisited) link you provided. There's almost no single point in that list-of-50 that matters in day-to-day usage. I wonder why people do those benchmarks. Yeah, a call to `print` is slower than one to `echo`: if you perform tens of millions of then it might scrape off a second of processing time. Who #@$ cares. And none of it is applicable to the OP, because he hasn't posted any code.

Comment: indeed there are 2 ore 3 hints I didn't know, but most of those are nothing that will solve the problem. I will profile a bit and look, where the problems are - probably the mysql-queries are to slow. Is there a faster DB? Is it possible to query the entire database and process everything within the php-script?

Comment: It's impossible to say exactly why your code is running slowly without actually profiling it. [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) will give you the information you need to determine what takes so long, but there's no way of knowing whether or not an optimisation will increase performance until you try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could rent some processing power from a hoster.

You should however find the source of the slowness. Analyze the points that take a lot of time. Is it disk access? Try a memory cache. Are the queries slow because they don't hit indexes for examlpe? Analyze and improve your queries. Does your code use massive loops of querying which could be done in a join? Then use a join.

Comment: I'd need to refactor the complete code (which I will do in half a year or so), it's just too big, to do it just now.. Do you know a hoster who would sell processing power for things like this?

Comment: You could take a look at Amazon, as suggested by @Mathew Hall. Or look at a Virtual Private Server. But again, is it worth the money? Can't you run a batch of simulations overnight?

Comment: I do actually. But I'd love to just simulate, change something, simulate again, and so on. Is there a faster DB than MySQL?